# Should I concatenate three lists together or use two separate while loops in Python? Which option offers a better runtime complexity?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, python

In the context of adding sparse polynomials, you have two alternative approaches to combine the terms from two separate polynomials. One option is to use the line of code `result += self.terms[i:] + other.terms[j:]`, which efficiently concatenates the remaining terms from both polynomials. The other option is to employ two separate while loops like the ones shown below:

```python
while i < len(self.terms):
    coeff, exp = self.terms[i]
    result.add_term(coeff, exp)
    i += 1

while j < len(other.terms):
    coeff, exp = other.terms[j]
    result.add_term(coeff, exp)
    j += 1
```

The first approach concatenates the remaining terms into a single list and appends them to the result, while the second approach iterates through the remaining terms in both polynomials and adds them to the result one by one.

The question at hand is: which of these options provides a better runtime complexity when adding sparse polynomials? Your input and insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated."

Answer (score 1):

First, measure. If you can’t measure the difference then it doesn’t matter.

Second, you don’t know the time complexity of add_term. You need to find its implementation and analyse its behaviour. Reasonable implementations could lead to a runtime that is quadratic in the number of terms. Different reasonable implementations would lead to linear or n log n behaviour.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c353764fd564e401cf47a5d9efab18c72c60014e/Objects/listobject.c#L440  I provided following link, I assume "+" would use list_concat that is implemented here.

Answer (score 0):

about slicing I would suggest to check following link: [implementation of list slicing](https://www.quora.com/How-is-slicing-implemented-in-python) and also following answer on [big O of list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203601/big-o-of-list-slicing) .  also try to find list_concat method here [source code of cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c353764fd564e401cf47a5d9efab18c72c60014e/Objects/listobject.c#L440). I assume that list-slicing and list_concat that are internal staff of python would be fast because of C, so instead of doing it yourself, use slicing and "+" operator.  however I would suggest to separately run both program on relatively large lists ($10^6$ size at least and check the time it took).